How to convert type to generic type, whose actual type is known at the point of conversion?
I have a set of methods which simply return a stored 'object' as a different type each, like this:
bool GetAsBool();
string GetAsString();
int GetAsInt();

In the real scenario, there are currently 16 of these, and the method names are a little longer, making them not great to read. I was now looking to make it more convenient by defining a single generic method which selects the correct method from this set of "Get" methods. This would give syntax highlighting for the type passed via the generic, and make the name shorter, which I feel would be easier to read in the end. But I cannot figure out how to do the type conversion.
The generic method currently looks something like this:
T Get<T>()
{
    var returnTpe = typeof(T);
    if (returnType == typeof(bool) { return GetAsBool(); }
    else if (returnType == typeof(string) { return GetAsString(); }
    else if (returnType == typeof(int) { return GetAsInt(); }
    else { return default; }
}

This gives me Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'T' (for bool, similar for the other types). But I do know, from the if-clause, which type the T is by the time I get there. So the type of "T" and the return type of the method I select always match. This should mean the conversion is always possible, right? How do I convert my typed result back to T?
I've only tried a simple cast so far, via return (T)GetAsBool(), which gives me Cannot convert type 'bool' to 'T'. I'm no expert regarding types or generics and googling has not resulted in any more ideas on my end. Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

return default should not be used here (because it prevents consumers from detecting error conditions). You should throw an exception instead - or use a Boolean TryGet( out T value )-style method.

What is the benefit of doing this vs just exposing GetAsString etc? But if you really want to, check https://dotnetfiddle.net/MpXwvz .

The "Cannot convert type 'bool' to 'T'" error is because you're mixing value-types and reference-types in a single generic-method. One workaround is to apply a boxing-conversion to all value-types by performing an intermediate cast to Object - but this is inefficient as it results in heap allocations.

Please don't share code with so many obvious typos.

You misunderstand how generics work. In order to call a generic method, you still have to know the generic type when you write the code to make the method call. It doesn't get deferred until run time. You would still have to write something like var str = Get<string>(); so there's literally no advantage to doing that over var str = GetAsString();. The point of generics is to enable you to write code once and have it work for multiple different types, not to allow you to have defer type-checking until run time.

@Dai It's nothing to do with boxing. Trying to cast a reference type to T without any generic constraint would have the same issue. It's because the compiler cannot guarantee a safe cast to T.

@jmcilhinney There could be a benefit if Get<T> is called frequently in other generic methods. It would prevent these type checks from happening in multiple places.

To get what you are asking for you can double-cast, first to object and then to T, and it will compile. I'm not sure how efficient this is for structs since they will probably get boxed, but it is fine for objects.
if (returnType == typeof(bool) { return (T)(object)GetAsBool(); }

But if you really want brief syntax I suggest ditching the Get method altogether and defining conversion operators instead.
static public explicit operator bool(MyClass source) => source.GetAsBool();
static public explicit operator string(MyClass source) => source.GetAsString();

Then people using your class can just cast it to the type they want, and if the cast isn't supported, there is a compile-time error.
var x = (bool)myObject;
var y = (string)myObject;


Did not know about the conversion operator approach yet, works even better. Thank you!
